# Sequelize $or not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The query below is not using the `$or` operator properly.  Is my syntax wrong?

```
models.Accounts
    .find({ where: { 
              venue_id: req.body.venue_id,
              $or: [{
                organization_id: req.body.organization_id//,
                //venue_id: null
              }]
            }
          })
    .then(function(result) {
     console.log(result)
    }
```

the sql it is generating looks like this.

```
SELECT `id`, `uuid`, `venue_id`, `organization_id`, `labor_service_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `accounts` AS `Accounts` WHERE `Accounts`.`venue_id` = NULL AND (`Accounts`.`organization_id` = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given answers are outdated. With current sequelize, you want to use
[`Operators`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators) for such operations. For this use case there is `Op.or` which is used like this:

```js
import { Op } from 'sequelize';

models.Accounts
    .findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { organization_id: req.body.organization_id },
                { venue_id: req.body.venue_id }
            ]
        }
    })
```

Also be aware that the current [finders](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html) are `findOne`, `findAll` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

From [official docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html) the proper way of making `OR` queries is putting individual objects for each statement to be joined by `OR` in the array, like the following-

```
$or: [{a: 5}, {a: 6}]
```

So in your case, you should write-

```
models.Accounts
    .find({
        where: {
            $or: [
                { organization_id: req.body.organization_id },
                { venue_id: req.body.venue_id }
                //venue_id: null
            ]
        }
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
models.Accounts
.find({ where: { 
          $or: [{
            venue_id: req.body.venue_id,
            organization_id: req.body.organization_id//,
            //venue_id: null
          }]
        }
      })
.then(function(result) {
 console.log(result)
}
```